# Form submission using form array?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

My app.html is like below.

```
<form [formGroup]="CompanyGroup" (ngSubmit)="groupCompany(CompanyGroup.value)">
<div formArrayName="mapRow">
  <h4>UNMAPPED COMPANIES</h4>
<div class="row unmapped">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Bank Name</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Add to a Group</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let unmapped of unmappedCompanies ">
        <td>{{unmapped.cname}}</td>
        <td>{{unmapped.bname}}</td>
        <td>{{unmapped.id}}</td>
        <td>

                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                   <select  name="add_group" formControlName="add_group" class="form-control">
                     <option value="">Please Select the Group</option>
                     <option *ngFor="let grp of groups" class="select-group"  [value]="grp.id">{{grp.company_name}}</option>
                   </select>
                 </div>
            <input value="unmapped.id" type="hidden" formControlName="companies_id" name="companies_id">   

         </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success add_group" >Add</button>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

when i click Add button i want to submit all the data . So i am using FormArray.
My .ts file is as below.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.CompanyGroup=this.fb.group({
      'mapRow':this.fb.array([this.initItemRows()]),
    });
     this.getUnMappedCompanies();
     this.getAllCompanyGroups();
  }

  initItemRows() {
    return this.fb.group({
        add_group: ['', Validators.required],
        companies_id:['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

But it is giving error .

Can any one guide me on how to take values from input using formarray.

I want the output after submission like

```
{
  "add_group": "",
  "companies_id": ""
},
{
  "add_group": "",
  "companies_id": ""
}
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: where is the implementation of  the method `groupCompany` ?

Comment: When you are getting your `unmappedCompanies`, iterate that array and push the values to formArray as Formgroups.